# I need to do changes just on specific words

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a String problem for the Java 8 streams. They want me to change all the first letter into uppercase letter just if the words aren't into "the", "a", "to", "of", "in" group.

My problem is that the `filter` command does delete the words from the group and I have to keep them.

I have already done the part for the upper case first letter but I have no idea how to make the "jump" over the group of words

```
private List<String> ignoredWords = Arrays.asList("the", "a", "to", "of", "in");
String entryParts[] = toTitlelize.split(" ");

List<String> sentenceParts = Arrays.asList(entryParts);
List<String> finalSentence = sentenceParts.stream()            
        .map(WordUtils::capitalize)
        .collect(toList());
```

For example :

```
if toTitlelize = "I love to eat pizza in my home"
```

It should return

> "I Love to Eat Pizza in My Home"

for the moment it gives me:

> "I Love To Eat Pizza in My Home"

Comment: You can choose to implement `capitalize` in such a way that it ignores the words from `ignoredWords` collection as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `if` statement in you mapping step:

```
List<String> finalSentence = Arrays.stream(entryParts)
        .map(word -> {
            if (ignoredWords.contains(word)) {
                return word;
            }
            return WordUtils.capitalize(word);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As an alternative you can use `filter()` and `findFirst()` on the `ignoredWords` and use an `Optional`:

```
List<String> finalSentence = Arrays.stream(entryParts)
        .map(word -> ignoredWords.stream().filter(w -> w.equals(word)).findFirst().orElse(WordUtils.capitalize(word)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I also would recommend to use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, because the words are unique and `contains()` is much faster:

```
HashSet<String> ignoredWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("the", "a", "to", "of", "in"));
```

The result of `String.join(" ", finalSentence);` will be:

> I Love to Eat Pizza in My Home